# jQuery onChange prop a value to inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select, onchange

I have a `<select>` drop down that I'm inserting into my HTML via jQuery. I don't have control over the HTML but I do have control over the JavaScript.

I'm trying to prop a value to an `<input>` element when you select an option. Basically, I have a `<select>` element with `<option id="1">` and `<option id="2">` *onChange* of this `<select>` element; 
If you select `option#1` it should prop the value **dummy1** to `input[name="Check_Config_PaymentGateway_CreditCards_Login1"]` and the value **dummy2** to `input[name="Check_Config_PaymentGateway_CreditCards_Password"]`
If you select `option#2` it should prop the value **dummy3** to `input[name="Check_Config_PaymentGateway_CreditCards_Login1"]` and the value **dummy4** to `input[name="Check_Config_PaymentGateway_CreditCards_Password"]`

I've been working on this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VW9N6/).

I'm pretty new at JavaScript in general, let alone jQuery. This is way to sophisticated for my skill... If you can help me, I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:  http://jsfiddle.net/VW9N6/6/

This binds to the `change` event of the `<select>` element to detect when its value changes, and then updates the value of the `<input>` elements.

Comment: Simple, Understandable, Perfect :)

Comment: Not to be negative, but this is pretty inefficient. You don't cache the inputs and will be re-creating them every onchange. Furthermore, you aren't taking advantage of chaining in jQuery. You don't need to create a separate function and then call it from inside the change handler and inline for initial page load. Simply put the function contents in the handler and chain .change() on afterwards to immediately invoke the handler. Look at my answer for both caching and chaining.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below,

**Edit:** Cached input text boxes.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/VW9N6/1/)

```
var dummyValues = [['dummy1', 'dummy2'], ['dummy3', 'dummy4']];

var $loginInput = $('input[name=Check_Config_PaymentGateway_CreditCards_Login1]');
var $pwdInput = $('input[name=Check_Config_PaymentGateway_CreditCards_Password]');

$('#paymentDD').change(function () {
  var selectedVal = parseInt($(this).val(), 10) - 1;
  $loginInput.val(dummyValues [selectedVal][0]);
  $pwdInput.val(dummyValues [selectedVal][1]);
});
```

Updated `dummyValues` var as you add move options to the drop down.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a fan of caching elements whenever possible, so that's what I do. I also saw that you were using the latest jQuery (1.7.2) in your jsFiddle, so why not use the recommended **[`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** method and then call an immediate **[`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/)** to populate on load?

***[You could try something like this:](http://jsfiddle.net/qM5Kg/)***

```
var $span = $('span#print_pagename'),
    $login = $('input[name="Check_Config_PaymentGateway_CreditCards_Login1"]'),
    $password = $('input[name="Check_Config_PaymentGateway_CreditCards_Password"]'),
    $select = $('<select><option id="1">1</option><option id="2">2</option></select>');

$span.after($select);

$select.on('change', function() {

    var $this = $(this);

    if ($this.val() === '1') {

        $login.val('dummy1');
        $password.val('dummy2');

    } else if ($this.val() === '2') { 

        $login.val('dummy3');
        $password.val('dummy4');

    }

}).change();
```